# Substituing superclass by another one using objective-c runtime

Tags: objective-c, runtime

Is it possible using the Objective-C runtime to replace a class by another ?

For instance I have a class "Parent" which is the parent of "ChildA", "ChildB", "ChildC", "ChildD" classes. 
I want to override a method implemented in "Parent" in a new class "NewChild" that would be the parent of the 4 "Child*" classes.
And I want to dynamically replace "Parent" by "NewChild", so if I make [ChildA new], I get an instance that is a subclass of "NewChild" which is a subclass of "Parent".

Is it possible to do this using obj-c runtime ? and if so, is it safe ?

Comment: What do you want to archie here? As i understand, you want to call the overide method by a dynamic way. Is it right?

Comment: Not at all. I want to put a new class in the inheritance tree between "Parent" and "ChildA" ... It is in a library that is already compiled, so I can only do this using runtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to do this using obj-c runtime ? and if so, is it safe ?

*Short Answers:* No and Probably Not

*Explanation:*

Historically, and it seems for a brief period, there was a runtime method to set the superclass of a class, which would in theory enable what you seek, but this has long been not only deprecated but marked as "do not use".

Even if you choose to violate that warning and contrive to change the superclass chain you are entering the world of "Here Be Dragons".

A fundamental challenge to succeeding are `super` calls. A standard method call is based off the *runtime* type, and inheritance chain, of an object. However a `super` call is based off the static class a method was in *at the time of compilation*. Therefore, though you can *swizzle* methods – which involves dynamically changing the class a particular method implementation is associated with at runtime – if such a method makes any `super` calls then those are relative to the methods *compile time* class. As you later add in a comment:

> It is in a library that is already compiled, so I can only do this using runtime.

then attempting to splice in, ignoring the "Do Not Use" warning, a compiled class, which could have `super` calls within it without your knowledge, into a different inheritance chain is likely to result in chaos.

For the same reason, if you don't have the source of the class you wish to splice in then using method swizzling to splice in the method's code, *without* messing with the inheritance chain, is also risky.

If you do have the source of the method you wish to splice in and know it makes no `super` calls, then you can consider swizzling – you have three method implementations to consider, the method in `Parent`, the method in `NewChild`, and a third you would write to swizzle into `Parent` which was responsible for calling the implementation from `NewChild` before calling the one from `Parent`.

If you **really** wish to go this route you need to study how swizzling works (there are good Q&A's on SO, but I'm biased ;-)) to make sure you weave the implementations together correctly. **However** the recommendation is you consider a different design for your application first and solve your problem a different way. Remember when messing with the runtime: *Here Be Dragons*!

HTH